# Pass an array of Lat Long in WayPoints Google Maps API 3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How to pass an array of Latitude and Longitude inside waypoints object and then pass it to the directionservice object for drawing the route?

If i want to pass a single lat long we would pass it as below

```
    waypoints: 
[{
     location:new google.maps.LatLng(42.496403,-124.413128),
     stopover:false
}],
```

But how do i pass an array of Latitude and Longitude?

Please find the code that i have tried(It throws a script error):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Lat long way points (LatLng)</title>
<style type="text/css"> 
html { height: 100% }
body { height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  var directionDisplay;
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  var map;

  function initialize() {
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 6,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      center: chicago
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    calcRoute();
  }

  function calcRoute() {
      var first=new google.maps.LatLng(42.496403,-124.413128);
      var second=new google.maps.LatLng(42.496401,-124.413126);
      var values=[first,second];
      alert(values[0]);
      alert(values[1]);
      var waypts=[];
      alert(values.length); 
    for(var i=0;i<=values.length;i++)
    {
     waypts.push({location:values[i],stopover:true}); 
    }
     alert(waypts);
    var request = {
        origin: "1521 NW 54th St, Seattle, WA 98107 ",
        destination: "San Diego, CA",
        waypoints: waypts,
        optimizeWaypoints: true,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.WALKING
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        var route = response.routes[0];
        var summaryPanel = document.getElementById("directions_panel");
        summaryPanel.innerHTML = "";
        // For each route, display summary information.
        for (var i = 0; i < route.legs.length; i++) {
          var routeSegment = i + 1;
          summaryPanel.innerHTML += "<b>Route Segment: " + routeSegment + "</b><br />";
          summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].start_address + " to ";
          summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].end_address + "<br />";
          summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].distance.text + "<br /><br />";
        }
      } else {
        alert("directions response "+status);
      }
    });
  }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
<div id="map_canvas" style="float:left;width:70%;height:100%;"></div>
<div id="control_panel" style="float:right;width:30%;text-align:left;padding-top:20px">
<div id="directions_panel" style="margin:20px;background-color:#FFEE77;"></div>
</div>
<script src="http://www.google-analytics.com/urchin.js" type="text/javascript"> 
</script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think I understand the question, why would you want an array to be passed to the waypoint object? Each waypoint is merely one stop along a route?

Comment: Do you mean you want to pass multiple waypoints? They use seperate objects I believe.

Answer (score 23):

this is how to add multiple waypoints

```
waypoints: [{location: first, stopover: false},
                        {location: second, stopover: false}],
```

the complete code for your sample

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <title>Lat long way points (LatLng)</title>
        <style type="text/css"> 
            html { height: 100% }
            body { height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var directionDisplay;
            var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
            var map;

            function initialize() {
                directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
                var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523);
                var myOptions = {
                    zoom: 6,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                    center: chicago
                };
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
                directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
                calcRoute();
            }

            function calcRoute() {
                var first = new google.maps.LatLng(42.496403, -124.413128);
                var second = new google.maps.LatLng(42.496401, -124.413126);

                var request = {
                    origin: "1521 NW 54th St, Seattle, WA 98107 ",
                    destination: "San Diego, CA",
                    waypoints: [{location: first, stopover: false},
                        {location: second, stopover: false}],
                    optimizeWaypoints: true,
                    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.WALKING
                };
                directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                        var route = response.routes[0];
                        var summaryPanel = document.getElementById("directions_panel");
                        summaryPanel.innerHTML = "";
                        // For each route, display summary information.
                        for (var i = 0; i < route.legs.length; i++) {
                            var routeSegment = i + 1;
                            summaryPanel.innerHTML += "<b>Route Segment: " + routeSegment + "</b><br />";
                            summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].start_address + " to ";
                            summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].end_address + "<br />";
                            summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].distance.text + "<br /><br />";
                        }
                    } else {
                        alert("directions response " + status);
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="initialize()">
        <div id="map_canvas" style="float:left;width:70%;height:100%;"></div>
        <div id="control_panel" style="float:right;width:30%;text-align:left;padding-top:20px">
            <div id="directions_panel" style="margin:20px;background-color:#FFEE77;"></div>
        </div>
        <script src="http://www.google-analytics.com/urchin.js" type="text/javascript">
        </script> 
        <script type="text/javascript">
        </script> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I wish the google maps API had this example on their page! Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

The example here should help: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions?hl=cs#Waypoints

Effectively assign the waypoints object to an array e.g:

```
waypoints : waypointsArray
```

Where the array contains multiple waypoint objects e.g.:

```
  {
      location: LatLng,
      stopover:true
  }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @ Swires : Thanks for the reference, I have multiple stops in the form of lat long between source and destination. In the example provided by you it allows me to store an array inside waypoints but it is for places. +1 for the same. But how do i do the same for Lat Long?

Comment: Simply provide a LatLng in place of an address in the above call as indicated. So for each object in the array you have location : yourLatLng.

Comment: Yes i have done that. I have attached my code. But it throws a Js script error.

Comment: [Example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_directions-waypointsC.html) using a LatLng as a waypoint.

Answer (score 0):

The most upvoted solution did not work for me, as some part of the code seems obsolete. Hence, I am posting my code. The following solutions works for me in **2023**.

Simply replace the `XXXXXXXXXXXX` in the script tag with your Google Maps API key and the run the example in your browser and you should be good to go:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>Lat long way points (LatLng)</title>
    <style>
        /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
        html,
        body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #container {
            height: 100%;
            display: flex;
        }

        #sidebar {
            flex-basis: 15rem;
            flex-grow: 1;
            padding: 1rem;
            max-width: 30rem;
            height: 100%;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            overflow: auto;
        }

        #map {
            flex-basis: 0;
            flex-grow: 4;
            height: 100%;
        }

        #directions-panel {
            margin-top: 10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="sidebar">
        <div>
            <b>Start:</b>
            <select id="start">
                <option value="Halifax, NS">Halifax, NS</option>
                <option value="Boston, MA">Boston, MA</option>
                <option value="New York, NY">New York, NY</option>
                <option value="Miami, FL">Miami, FL</option>
            </select>
            <br/>
            <b>Waypoints:</b> <br/>
            <i>(Ctrl+Click or Cmd+Click for multiple selection)</i> <br/>
            <select multiple id="waypoints">
                <option value="montreal, quebec">Montreal, QBC</option>
                <option value="toronto, ont">Toronto, ONT</option>
                <option value="chicago, il">Chicago</option>
                <option value="winnipeg, mb">Winnipeg</option>
                <option value="fargo, nd">Fargo</option>
                <option value="calgary, ab">Calgary</option>
                <option value="spokane, wa">Spokane</option>
            </select>
            <br/>
            <b>End:</b>
            <select id="end">
                <option value="Vancouver, BC">Vancouver, BC</option>
                <option value="Seattle, WA">Seattle, WA</option>
                <option value="San Francisco, CA">San Francisco, CA</option>
                <option value="Los Angeles, CA">Los Angeles, CA</option>
            </select>
            <br/>
            <input type="submit" id="submit"/>
        </div>
        <div id="directions-panel"></div>
    </div>
</div>


<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXXXXXXXXXX&callback=initMap" defer></script>
<script>
    function initMap() {
        const directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        const directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
        const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
            zoom: 6,
            center: { lat: 41.85, lng: -87.65 },
        });

        directionsRenderer.setMap(map);
        document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", () => {
            calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsRenderer);
        });
    }

    function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsRenderer) {
        const waypts = [];
        const checkboxArray = document.getElementById("waypoints");

        for (let i = 0; i < checkboxArray.length; i++) {
            if (checkboxArray.options[i].selected) {
                waypts.push({
                    location: checkboxArray[i].value,
                    stopover: true,
                });
            }
        }

        directionsService
            .route({
                origin: document.getElementById("start").value,
                destination: document.getElementById("end").value,
                waypoints: waypts,
                optimizeWaypoints: true,
                travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
            })
            .then((response) => {
                directionsRenderer.setDirections(response);

                const route = response.routes[0];
                const summaryPanel = document.getElementById("directions-panel");

                summaryPanel.innerHTML = "";

                // For each route, display summary information.
                for (let i = 0; i < route.legs.length; i++) {
                    const routeSegment = i + 1;

                    summaryPanel.innerHTML +=
                        "<b>Route Segment: " + routeSegment + "</b><br>";
                    summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].start_address + " to ";
                    summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].end_address + "<br>";
                    summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].distance.text + "<br><br>";
                }
            })
            .catch((e) => window.alert("Directions request failed due to " + status));
    }

    window.initMap = initMap;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The above solution is obtained from the official source at: [Google Maps - Waypoints in Directions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-waypoints)